# What is the reason that Asnyc Express Midleware works?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, promise, async-await

Hi I am new to Express/Node and was looking for guidance and explanation.

If I have an asyc function as a middleware, this inherently immediately returns a promise. Let us mock up a function.

```js
async function verifyToken() {
    try {
        await API call...
        next() // <-- continue to the next middleware if the api call was successful
    } catch (err) {
        // catch exceptions from api call
        }
    }
```

I am wondering now when I use this function like so:

```
 this.router.get("/test", verifyToken, (req, res) => {
 res.send("GET TEST");
});
```

If the verifyToken is async doesn't that mean it gets called immediately returns a Promise and then node continues its execution? How do asynchronous methods work as middleware?

Comment: It does get called immediately but anywhere there is an `await` keyword the code is recompiled into `API call.then(next)` therefore the `await` will always work regardless if `.then()` is ever called. This is true for any promise returning function. Try calling `verifyToken` yourself outside of the middleware: `verifyToken({},{},()=>console.log('next was called'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the verifyToken is async doesn't that mean it gets called immediately returns a Promise and then node continues its execution? How do asynchronous methods work as middleware?

You are right that the `async` function immediately returns a promise as soon as it hits an `await` inside.  But, even though Express isn't paying any attention to the returned promise there, that can still work just fine because of the Express design.

Express anticipates in its design the need for asynchronous middleware (whether using promises or not).  As such, it calls your middleware, passes it the `req`, and `res` objects and a `next` callback and then does nothing after that.  Literally nothing.  It's done with further processing at that point until you do one of two things - either send a response with something like `res.send()` or call `next()`.  If you send a response, that's pretty self explanatory.  If you call `next()`, then that tells Express to follow the chain of handlers for this request and find the next matching request handler and call it.

So, here are the steps when this route matches:

```
async function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    try {
        await API call...
        next() // <-- continue to the next middleware if the api call was successful
    } catch (err) {
        // catch exceptions from api call
    }
}

this.router.get("/test", verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    res.send("GET TEST");
});
```

1. nodejs first calls `verifyToken()` and passes it `req, res, next`.
2. That function hits the `await`, makes the API call, suspends further execution of the function and then immediately returns a pending promise
3. The return goes back into Express and it just returns back to whatever networking event informed it about the incoming request and there's nothing else to do there.
4. Then, for a little while nothing is happening.
5. Then, your API call finishes at some point and the promise that is being awaited gets resolved.  That restarts the execution of the function at the line of code after the `await`.
6. That calls `next()` which goes back into Express and, using data in a closure for the `next()` callback, it knows which handler to call next and it calls the final request handler in your route which calls `res.send()`.
7. That handler returns and Express is done. Since you didn't call `next()` from the last handler, Express will do no more work on that request.

---

Express was designed awhile ago and thus isn't innately promise-aware.  But, it was designed with asynchronous operation in mind so promises can still be used with the framework just fine - you just hook up promise event handlers to the the appropriate Express callbacks.  Because express isn't watching the promise that your `async` function returned, it is imperative you make sure you catch all rejections yourself because Express won't catch them for you.

There is a cousin of Express called koa that is more designed around promises and does have automatic error handling for rejected promises.

Answer (score 0):

When a request arrives in your application, it first comes to your app middleware, then to the router middleware and finally to your router defined function.
When a middleware is executed it only passes the request to the next step if the next() function is called. The value that the middleware returns (if it returns something) is not readed or used by any part of the application.
I think that if the middleware is asynchronous or not is not important at all, cause express will only continue its execution once the next() function is called.